# Make div2 visible after div1 is hidden || Javascript

Tags: javascript, hidden, visible

I have two classes, div1 and div2. div1 is a countdown and div2 is a captcha. I want div2 to be visible in page only after div1 is hidden :

```
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2" style="display:none"></div>
```

Now how can I make a javascript for that?

Comment: ofcourse you can but have you tried anything for it.

Comment: I tried a javascript that makes div2 visible after a time delay like this : 
`$(function() {
  $(".div2").delay(10000);
});` ... but I need to make the visibility of div2 depending on the hidden of div1.

Comment: .captcha is a class which class you are using for the delay...anyways give description and you can do your work after checking div1 is hidden or not like if($(".div1").style.display==none){$(".div2").show();}else{$(".div2").hide();}

Comment: Sorry not captcha but the class is ( div2 ) I meant.  I need a correct writing of a script like this : `if($(".div1").("hidden")){ .div2("visible");} else {$(.div2).("hidden")}`

Comment: @Zorba are you using JQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you just toggle div2's visibility with JS when toggling div1? I assume you're using JS to hide div1 so surely there you can toggle div2 in the same block of code?

#### Using jQuery

```
<style>
  .div2 {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>

$('.div1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('.div2').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

?

#### Checking visibility?

```
if ($('.div1').is(':visible')) {
  $('.div2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

OR do you want your code separate and so you want to trigger an event from the div1 script when it hides so div2's script activates it's own script to action?

Comment: Yes I already use a JS to hide div1. I need a separate JS to only show div2 after div1 is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using JQuery as your code in the comment section looks like JQuery. So this is how I would solve using JQuery.

Keep `count-down div` shown , while `captcha div` hidden using `hidden = "true"`.

Then as soon as count down is over, you can toggle both divs

`$(countDownDiv).toggle(); // this will hide it`

`$(captchaDiv).toggle();   // this will make it visible`

Comment: I need to use a separate Jquery code to make div2 visible once div1 is hidden, would you please give me the full code

Comment: @Zorba You need to put some effort from your side also